# Best practices for file and directory permissions in a multi-user environment

Tags: files, permissions, configuration, users

This is my situation in an experimental environment.

- A php script is creating files in a target directory when it's executed from Apache via web request.
  It runs as `www-data` user, the created files have this user and group. Of course the target directory must have appropriate permissions for this user.
- A cronjob processes the file and moves it to an archive directory.
  The cron job runs as user `adminuser`. This is the user I log in to administrate the computer, so I want it to be able to access files and cronjobs and the like.

I got this to work by chown'ing target and archive directory to `adminuser:www-data` (files can be created) and adding `adminuser` to group `www-data` (then cronjobs and I can access them).

But I still wonder what is best practice to configure that? Would it be advisable to create a new group that both users are in and assign this group to the directories?
I have practically no experience and appreciate any input.

Comment: your current approach seems sensible.

Comment: The target directory does not have to be owned by `adminuser`. It obviously has write permission for the group (otherwise `www-data` could not create files there) so the `www-data` group settings should be enough for `adminuser` to read and delete files there. Don't forget to block access for `others`.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Correct, this is one of the things I might have missed and that made me ask here for opinions :-)

Comment: And a general hint for your question: Instead of describing what you did it would have been more useful to provide the output of `getfacl` for both directories.